# how to use context menu item in custom list android

Tags: android

I have implemented a `custom list view`. (using Activity and `ListRowAdapter` extending `BaseRowAdaptor`)

I set a `contextmenu` to listview setting

```
itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
       {

              menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");  
              menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 1");  
            // menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 2"); 

        }
    });
```

In `getView` method in my adapter class.

But How t handle the item select event?

I can catch that event in My `Activity`.

But how can i identify the row of the list view?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global int variable that contains the index of the item that you have selected. You would set the value of the variable in the listview onLongClick(), onClick(), etc event. Then when you are inside the context menu's item click event, you will have access the currently selected row in the listview.

Answer (score 0):

set LongClickListener to listview then showContext menu on longClick .

```
Class ActivityName extends Activity implements IconContextItemSelectedListener 
{  
    private IconContextMenu cmContextMenu;  
    private int selectedPosition ;

    onCreate() { 
        cmContextMenu = new IconContextMenu(this, R.menu.fbupdatecontextmenu);
        cmContextMenu.setOnIconContextItemSelectedListener(this);
        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long arg3) {
                selectedPosition = position;
                cmContextMenu.show();
                return true;            
            }
        });
    }

    public void onIconContextItemSelected(MenuItem item, Object info) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.someThing: {
            system.out.prinlt("position " +selectedPosition); 
            break;  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is because IconContextMenu is my custom class , code snippet was just for reference . you need to create your contextMenu and show it onLongclick .rest of thing you can keep as it is